# Bash script trying to compare a historical and current file and get a sum difference when lines dont match

Tags: bash, awk, diff, multiple-columns, cut

I have a bash script using diff -y and awk and comparing a historical file with a current file. The problem I run into is the historical file virtually always has a larger number of lines than the current state. And it varies as to which line will be missing from the current file. Below is what I would like the output to look like.

```
$ more Sum_difference.csv 

Historical=93   lag-123:1234  Current=92   lag-123:1234  |  Difference=  1

Historical=53   lag-133:2345  Current=52   lag-133:2345  |  Difference=  1

Historical=188  lag-144:3546  Current=189  lag-104:3654  |  Difference=  -1

Historical=106  lag-157:3457  Current=105  lag-157:3457  |  Difference=  1

Historical=133  lag-167:3458  Current=132  lag-167:3458  |  Difference=  1

Historical=8    lag-168:4657  Current=7    lag-168:4657  |  Difference=  1

Historical=168  lag-170:4566  Current=167  lag-170:4566  |  Difference=  1

Historical=96   lag-171:4568  Current=98   lag-171:4568  |  Difference=  -2

Historical=30   lag-172:4570  Current=31   lag-172:4570  |  Difference=  -1
```

What I get though is usually different than that. Example `cat historical.csv | wc -l` would equal 678 while the current might only show 500 lines. resulting in the output to look like the below example. Causing the difference to be incorrect.

```
$ more Sum_difference.csv 

Historical=93   lag-123:1234  Current=92   lag-123:1234  |  Difference=  1

Historical=53   lag-133:2345  Current=52   lag-133:2345  |  Difference=  1

Historical=188  lag-144:3546  Current=189  lag-104:3654  |  Difference=  -1

Historical=133  lag-167:3458  Current=105  lag-157:3457  |  Difference=  28

Historical=96   lag-171:4568  Current=132  lag-167:3458  |  Difference=  -36

Historical=30   lag-172:4570  Current=31   lag-172:4570  |  Difference=  -1
```

So in the below example if there is an entry in the historical that is not listed in the current it throws the lines and hence the count off, which in turn throws my sum difference off. I have been trying to figure out a way to remedy this to where it might output like the below example. I have tried doing this with comm , diff, sdiff, below is an example of what I would like to be accomplished.

```
$ more Sum_difference.csv 

Historical=93   lag-123:1234  Current=92   lag-123:1234  |  Difference=  1

Historical=53   lag-133:2345  Current=52   lag-133:2345  |  Difference=  1

Historical=188  lag-144:3546  Current=189  lag-104:3654  |  Difference=  -1

Historical=106  lag-157:3457                          Not Present   |  Not present <<<< 

Historical=133  lag-167:3458  Current=132  lag-167:3458  |  Difference=  1

Historical=8    lag-168:4657               Not Present   |  Not present <<<< 

Historical=168  lag-170:4566  Current=167  lag-170:4566  |  Difference=  1

Historical=96   lag-171:4568  Current=98   lag-171:4568  |  Difference=  -2

Historical=30   lag-172:4570  Current=31   lag-172:4570  |  Difference=  -1
```

What I am basically doing is taking the historical and current files and sorting the output and counting the duplicates in each file, I then need to compare the two files and get the difference in the number of duplicates, for each line. With the historical file traditionally containing more lines/rows that the current file its causing them to be mismatched. The command I am using to sort the two files is below.

```
Current = grep lag | cut -d '"' -f2 | cut -d '.' -f1 | awk '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq -c

Historical = cut -c1-12 | sort | grep lag | uniq -c
```

The sorting and counting of duplicates works great, its just if a line is in the historical and not in the current I need to insert a blank space with something like "not present" in the line it would normally be at in the current file. I am just not sure exactly how to do this.

Is there a way to possibly "cat historical grep current and if matching field is not present to add a space or word to fill the space. Can this be done with sed? Thanks to everyone and I appreciate any help I could get on this. My apologies if this has been long winded.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but for similar tasks I rather user comm over diff as its output is more easy to parse.

Comment: Hi Eran, I appreciate your response, I tried comm but I am just not familiar with it enough I guess, I had tried doing comm -23 historical.csv current.csv , but I was getting

Comment: comm: file 2 is not in sorted order
comm: file 1 is not in sorted order

Comment: Which I am pretty sure is due to the fact that I am doing a "uniq -c" when I am initially sorting the files. I am basically trying to sort both files , then read the history file and check to see if that line exists in the current file if it does then +/- the number of duplicates that uniq -c found for that line. And if line 3 for example exists in historical but does not exist in the current file to copy the number generated by uniq -c over to the current file as say "23 down" if the historical file has 23 duplicates counted for said lag-123:4567 for example. I tried comm -23 file1 file2 but

Comment: I get  the below because of the duplicate entries uniq -c generates                                                                                                 comm: file 2 is not in sorted order
comm: file 1 is not in sorted order

Comment: You can't diff unsorted files either. Just that diff does not warn you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

since you didn't post your input files, I'll work on a sample and show a solution for what I think your problem is.

Each file has a number of repeated keys

```
==> file1 <==
a
a
a
b
b
c
c
e

==> file2 <==
a
a
c
d
e
e
```

We're trying to diff the counts, possibly with missing keys.  Although the input files are sorted, they don't need to be; output order is not specified, perhaps you need to sort it based on the keys (or diffs).

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next} {b[$1]++} 
       END    {print "key","count1","count2","diff"; 
               for(k in a) {bk=(k in b)?b[k]:0; 
                            print k,a[k],bk,a[k]-bk; 
                            delete b[k]} 
               for(k in b) print k,0,b[k],-b[k]}' file1 file2 | 
  column -t

key  count1  count2  diff
a    3       2       1
b    2       0       2
c    2       1       1
e    1       2       -1
d    0       1       -1
```

Comment: karakfa!!!!!  your so awesome!! thats exactly what I was trying to figure out. Dang I just wish I would have asked you this a month ago LOL. you have no idea how much time you just saved me! so awesome, too cool. this was being done in excel sometimes to check 10 to 50k entries could take like 10 to 20 min sometimes. Man thanks again, for all your help.

Comment: please uptick and accept this as the answer if you think so.  Also, if you can post the timings of this script with your data if will be useful.

Comment: Well not sure exactly how to time it, but I ran it against 50+ thousand entries and it worked virtually immediately I mean like less than a second. I green checked this as the correct answer but not sure really how to uptick?

Comment: use `time awk ... ` to get the running time information.  don't worry about the up vote, perhaps you're not qualified yet based on you points here...

Comment: Here ya go dood

Comment: real    0m0.008s
user    0m0.005s
sys     0m0.002s

Comment: That was the time to go through 7068 lines